# Having trouble to understand the MEAN.JS scaffolding and how Angular bootstraps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, template-engine, meanjs

Still learning the basics of MEAN and created a sample project from this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application), then decided to use some scaffolding tool to create clean folder structure for my project and i confronted [YEOMAN](http://yeoman.io/) and [MEANJS](http://meanjs.org/). Used `npm install -g yo`, `npm install -g generator-meanjs` and `yo meanjs`, everything worked like a charm n was having a project right infront me. You can download the entire [MEAN project here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/archive/v0.3.3.zip). 
Few things which i just dont understand despite of analyzing code structure for whole day :

1. How is Angular getting bootstrapped / loaded here ? Entire Angular
   stuff is residing inside `public` folder and who bootsrapps it ?
2. What is the use of some **HTML** files in `app/views` folder ? Especially files like `index.server.view.html` and `layout.server.view.html` are serving
   as templates of all other Angular view files / HTML files. How are
   they even getting hooked up ?
3. `application.js` is the AngularJS main
   application file and who is bringing this into life ?

Am not using anything like `Grunt` or `Gulp` or `Karma` for first cut of the application and may decide to scale it up later, so how do i remove those to get just a MEAN barebone architecture so that its easy to understand n get started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all your front-end stuff is inside `public` folder, and your question about the `app/views` folder is actually the answer to how your angular is bootstrapped:

- The `app/views` folder contains a single page of html that will be downloaded according to the route you requested to the server, so if you ask your server to render the `localhost:3000/`it will give you the `layout.html` and probably the `index.html` file. Your layout file may have a `ng-app="YourApp"`, and that's what bootstraps the angular, which is probably under your `application.js` file with something like `angular.module('YourApp')`. Note that `'YourApp'` MUST be the name of the directive `ng-app` in the layout/index file and that's how angular gets set up.
- Okay, knowing that you should note that `localhost:3000/home/` would render the `layout.html` plus `home.html` files, and so on. Therefore, each of these `app/views` pages should have several `partials` to work as a SPA application to the user, for example: `localhost:3000/home#profile` would be the same view page as the `localhost:3000/home#dashboard`, what changes is the angular partials.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur time man. What i understood after going through MEAN JS documentation is : they r using something called Swig template-engine that hooks Angular `public` folder views to `app/views` in MEAN stack. As you said my layout HTML file is not having anything like `ng-app="YourApp" `.

Comment: @BeingSuman your layout file doesn't have any `ng-app` reference because MEAN.JS 0.3.3 uses Angular [manual bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap). If you check your application.js file you will see this line: `angular.bootstrap(document, [ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName]);`

Comment: @user3632710 Thanks for that. The reason i stayed with MEAN.JS 0.3.3 is had some problems with `AngularJS Module Sub-Generator` command `$ yo meanjs:angular-module <module-name>`. But a question out of curiousity : does the latest MEAN.JS provide a better bootstrapping approach ?

Comment: The most recent version still uses the same manual bootstrapping.

Comment: @user3632710 Got one more question : in `config/init.js` there is `process.env.NODE_ENV`. I just wanted to know where this `process` variable is declared ?

Comment: `process` is a nodejs [global object](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process). You can use your gruntfile to control NODE_ENV, for example, some tasks may run in testing env and not in dev env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118865/discussion-between-beingsuman-and-user3632710).